# sums of row on graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure how to express the sum of rows of an adjacency matrix for a directed graph.  I know for an indirect it is deg(v).  I guess it would be an "out-degree" but I don't know how to represent that.

Answer (score 1):

One notation for the out-degree of a vertex $v$ of a graph $G$ is $\deg_G^+(v)$, where the subscript $G$ can be omitted if the identity of the graph is clear from the context. The corresponding notation for the in-degree is $\deg_G^-(v)$. I have seen other notations, but these seem to be fairly common.